# Postgresql: insert into two tables with valid FK using a JSON parameter for a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tableone (
  id            integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
  sampletextone text
);

CREATE TABLE tabletwo (
  id            integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
  tableone_id   int,
  sampletexttwo text
);
```

With the following `JSON` parameter sent to the procedure:

```
[
  {
    "sampletextone": "table one text 1",
    "tabletwo": 
      [
        {
            "sampletexttwo": "table two sample one text 1"
        },
        {
            "sampletexttwo": "table two sample one text 2"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "sampletextone": "table one text 2",
    "tabletwo": 
      [
        {
            "sampletexttwo": "table two sample one text 3"
        },
        {
            "sampletexttwo": "table two sample one text 4"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

I have the following `stored procedure`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure testproc(jsonparam json)
  AS 
$BODY$

  WITH ins1 AS (INSERT INTO "tableone" ("sampletextone") 
    SELECT prop->>'sampletextone'
    FROM json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop 
    Returning "id"
 )
 INSERT INTO "tabletwo" ("tableone_id", "sampletexttwo") 
 SELECT ins1."id", 'should be all sample text two'
 FROM ins1
 --JOIN json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE sql;
```

I am trying to join the `JSON` param again to insert all four rows in `tabletwo` with the correct foreign keys from `tableone`. I am not sure what would best way of joining the relevant data again.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=00add15ad48a94471c898b52e87dc02e)

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure testproc(jsonparam json)
 AS 
$BODY$

 WITH ins1 AS (INSERT INTO "tableone" ("sampletextone") 
 SELECT prop->>'sampletextone'
 FROM json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop 
 Returning "id", "sampletextone"
)
INSERT INTO "tabletwo" ("tableone_id", "sampletexttwo") 
SELECT ins1."id", json_extract_path(prop, 'tabletwo', 'sampletexttwo')
FROM ins1
JOIN json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop ON prop->>'sampletextone' = 
ins1."sampletextone"

$BODY$

LANGUAGE sql;
```

With the updated `stored procedure` only 2 rows created in `tabletwo` with the correct foreign keys instead of 4 and `sampletexttwo` is null

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure testproc(jsonparam json)
 AS 
$BODY$

WITH ins1 AS (INSERT INTO "tableone" ("sampletextone") 
 SELECT prop->>'sampletextone'
 FROM json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop 
 Returning "id", "sampletextone"
)
INSERT INTO "tabletwo" ("tableone_id", "sampletexttwo") 
SELECT ins1."id", json_array_elements(json_extract_path(prop, 'tabletwo'))->>'sampletexttwo'
FROM ins1
JOIN json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop ON prop->>'sampletextone' = 
ins1."sampletextone"

$BODY$

LANGUAGE sql;
```

If there is a better way of doing it, please let me know